# Game runs on wrong resolution

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I love laying this game on my phone, I have played it since I had a Nexus S.  After switching to the Galaxy S3, I found it didn't work well, so I just used my Nexus still, but now that device is broken, so I would like to figure out how to make it work on this device.

The game is called Legends of Yore, and the problem is that it displays very small. When I play it on my Nexus, it displays "normally" (phone mode), but on the S3 it displays it like it would on the computer (I'm going to call it tablet mode, because it's huge). It shoves everything that it would display on a desktop into the S3 screen, making buttons small and unusable.

I don't know much about how the game is coded, but I'm guessing that it is treating the S3's higher (than the Nexus) screen size, or pixel density, or whatever, as capable of running the game's tablet mode.

So, is there any way to make the game run in its phone mode?

This is kind of an old game, not very popular I don't think,  hasn't been updated in a long time, developer is unresponsive, and the official community forum has long been overrun with spam, so I am assuming that the developer doesn't really care about updating the app to work with modern phones, if that's indeed why it won't work right. But, I love playing this game, and I hope someone can help.

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like the developer needs to code their app to work on different screen sizes. There's not really anything you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The app IMO has not been configured for High Resolution screens and hence you see small buttons and are unable to play.

Comment: Is there any way to change that without having the source code or something?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like the game has two layouts and is switching between them based on the *resolution* of the screen (number of pixels) rather than the physical *size* of the screen. Android allows you to use either or both of these to choose a screen layout (amongst other things), but it's up to the app developer to get the criteria right and to test it on different devices. Using resolution instead of screen size is a common problem with software ported from PC, because most PC software makes the same mistake.

You can't work around this application error in stock Android. It would be possible for a [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom) to let you lie to the application about the resolution, but it would likely have undesirable side-effects (possibly making the game unusable anyway). I don't know if any ROMs do have this feature; trying one out requires replacing the operating system on your phone.

Changing the app to fix this problem would require reverse-engineering it. You'd require some programming experience to do this successfully, and doing so may be illegal in your country.